# Web and mobile app with cordova. Folder and installation structure (cordova.json? Gitignore?)

Tags: cordova

I'm planning to create an application for both the traditional web and for mobile devices. While planning the folder structure I came across a few problems. To build the app I'm thinking about using **nodejs** (npm), **bower, gulp, cordova** (android + possibly other platforms) and **git**.

This is the folder structure I have so far:

```
--Backend
--Frontend
    --Src
        --app
            app.js
        --assets
            --less
        index.html
    --Web
        // compiled files from src
    --Cordova
        --platforms
        --plugins
        --www
            // compiled files from src
            // ?cordova.json for platforms, plugins etc?
    --node_modules
    --bower_components
    package.json
    bower.json
    gulpfile.js
.gitignore
README.md
```

*Note: the folder structure only shows key folders/files and example content.*

My question mainly concerns **Cordova**, Is it possible to put the whole **Cordova** folder into **gitingore** and deploy it thorugh `npm install` from package.json? Is it possible to add **platforms**, **plugins** etc. to package.json? I've seen this in ionic but I'm not sure how to add them there, do I add them manually (*--save-dev seems not to work*)?

Does this folder structure make sense? Any general tips and thoughts that come to your head are highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Except if you have some other constraints for the structure I recommend you to do this.

A cordova/phonegap app is just a website included into a WebView (a browser) so you don't need to split you code between:

- codova
- web

You architecture can look like:

```
--src
  --platforms
  --plugins
  --www
    index.html
    //folders, images, css...
    --bower_components
--node_modules
package.json
bower.json
gulpfile.js
```

As it, you can deploy your www/ folder on your domain and create your APK/IPA with src/ folder content

EDIT: 
Use .bowerrc file to put you components into a sub folder http://bower.io/docs/config/

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I my source and production files are the same. Where do I output my .less files? My javascript mimification? Also my main concern is the app installation process (i.e. `npm install`);

Comment: You can create a folder nammed "dist" at the same level of "src". Your gulp/npm script can compile your less, minify.... into dist. Dist folder keep the same structure as "src". After, you build your app into a " bin" folder.